# While integrating AFT I am getting an error with code as 1110 In HMS

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

Getting error code 1110  while integrating AFT in HMS.
Checked the official documentation,
Rebuild the project
Taken mp3, wav format still getting same error,
Tried recording audio and providing as input still the same results

Comment: Is 1110 really the error code? It should be listed here: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/mlafterrors

Answer (score 0):

The error code 1110 is not complete. According the info you provided, the audio file format wav is correct. So please check as follows:

1. Check whether the size and the duration of the input audio file is within the supported range. The duration is less than 1 minute, and the size is less than 4 MB after Base64 encoding. The duration is less than 5 hours, and the size is 300 MB. Also in this version, both Chinese and English are supported.
2. After the above checking, please start the transcription task when the transcription engine is idle, and obtain the transcription result after the upload is complete. Check whether the parameters are correctly set.

For more info, please refer to [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/mlsdkaft-errorcode-0000001058399011-V5?ha_source=hms1).